# How much ETH will be minted per block (or epoch) after the docking/merge?

Tags: proof-of-stake, block-reward

I don't know if this has been decided already, but I can't find it anywhere. Simply put I'm looking for the number of ETH created per block (or any other timeframe) once Ethereum is fully POS.